# How can I change account type on Trello?

Tags: trello, google-account

Some time ago I created an account on Trello. Now I see that you can log in with a Google account. How can change my current Trello account to log in with my Google account?

Answer (score 1):

My own answer. If you log in with your google account is the same it login into your previous trello account.